# how to replace `bind(this)` in es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I read some codes:

```
class XXXX {
  init() {
    MyOBJ.on('EVENTNAME', this.myfunction.bind(this)); // Line3, MyOBJ extends EventEmitter
  }
}
```

Just curious how to use arrow function to replace Line3? Thanks

Comment: really @AlexanderNied - that won't call myfunction, ever

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) **creates a new function** that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

What this specific example - `this.myFunction.bind(this)` - achieves, is to be able to pass a reference to a function (that happens to also be referenced by this.myFunction) while making sure that any calls to that function are done in the context of `this`.

**In ES2015+ we can do this:**

```
class XXXX {
    init() {
        MyOBJ.on('EVENTNAME', (event) => this.myfunction(event));
    }
}
```

With ES2015 arrow functions `this` will inside the body be the declaration *context* of the arrow function. So in our case `this.myFunction` gets called in an arrow function whose context is the context of the call to `init()`, a.k.a. `this` within `init`.

The key difference is that now you actually create a call expression instead of just passing a reference to the function. This time the reference given to `MyOBJ.on` is the arrow function.

A strict ES5 equivalent to the snippet above would also use a function literal as callback given to `MyOBJ.on`:

```
class XXXX {
    init() {
        MyOBJ.on('EVENTNAME', function(event) {
            this.myfunction(event));
        }.bind(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you remove that listener though?

Comment: @PeterT You can do that, for instance, if you just have the arrow function as class property (as `this.myFunction`), and then call `MyObj.on('EVENTNAME', this.myFunction)`.

Comment: I discovered the result of `.bind()` creates a new function, so you need to assign that new function to a variable declared outside the listener to remove it. You need to do this because binding again creates *another* function: you need to store the original.

Answer (score 5):

**Replace this**

```
this.myfunction.bind(this)
```

**to this**

```
() => {}
```

**Your event binding would look as follow:**

```
class XXXX {
  someMethod() {}
  init() {
    MyOBJ.on('EVENTNAME', () => {
        this.someMethod(); // The originating context it's actually your class XXXX
    });
  }
}
```

## Resource

- [Javascript ES6 — Arrow Functions and Lexical `this`](https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4)

  > One of the most anticipated new features in the ES6 Javascript standard was the Arrow Function Expression. It promises a shorter syntax than it’s predecessor the Function Expression. In addition is how the new Arrow Function binds, or actually DOES NOT bind it’s own this. **Arrow Functions lexically bind their context so this actually refers to the originating context**.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you add your function to your object, you can simply do:

```
MyOBJ.on('EVENTNAME', this.someMethod);
```

Using arrow functions like this will bind the methods to the instance of the class.

```
class XXXX {
  constructor() {
    this.init();
  };

  someMethod = () => {
    console.log('someMethod() called');
  };

  init = () => {
    MyOBJ.on('EVENTNAME', this.someMethod);
  };
}

const x = new XXXX();
const MyOBJ = new EventEmitter();
MyOBJ.emit('EVENTNAME'); // someMethod() called
```

Note: using mocks to test for `this.someMethod` being called will likely fail if you use this method because the EventEmitter actually replaces the context of `this` inside `someMethod` when it's called. https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/1536 describes this issue.

Comment: *Using arrow functions like this* will cause syntax error, because that's ES6 question, and this is not ES6.