# Node - Why can't imported modules access global variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, import, global-variables

I've recently started using ES6 and properly compartmentalizing my code into multiple files for readability and easier version control and I've run into an issue that I'm not sure is intended, or if I'm missing something.

I have a class stored in a file (class.js) separate from my main script (main.js) and exported via module.exports. In main.js, class.js is required and I use it to create some instances of the class it houses. Inside main.js I have a global variable that is updated regularly, lets say connectedPlayers. Inside one of my methods of class.js I have usersOnline(), which should simply return the value of the global variable connectedPlayers. However, when I try to do this, I get thrown an error that connectedPlayers is not defined. I was under the impression that since the object that calls users.online was defined inside main.js, its usersOnline() method would look for connectedPlayers inside main.js, not class.js... is this correct thinking? If I am correct in that notion then why can't I access connectedPlayers? If I'm not correct in my thinking, how can I access connectedPlayers from inside my class?

Note these are all placeholders and I actually have quite a few global variables in main.js that I need methods inside of class.js to access. These global variables also change regularly so I can't necessarily pass them into the constructor, nor do I want to have to supply them for every call of whatever method I want to use. I'm sure there is a better way to do it, but how?

To clarify even further, the functionality I'm looking to get is similar to how in JS importing works in the browser, once you import your code it acts as if you concatenated that block of code to the code you're importing from. While I understand that's not how it works in node, I thought defining an instance of my class inside the main.js would essentially call the methods from that object (which is in the scope of connectedPlayers), but I guess my understanding is flawed.

Psuedo code:

```
//class.js
class user{
    constructor(id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    someOtherMethod(){
        ...
    }
    
    usersOnline(){
        this.someOtherMethod(this.id); //here to show I need the context to still be the obj
        return connectedPlayers;
    }
}

//main.js
var user = require('class.js');
var players = {}
var connectedPlayers = 0;

players[id] = new user(id);
console.log(players[id].usersOnline()) //expect to return value of connectedPlayers, but also execute the other function inside of usersOnline properly.
```

Also, in this example I could simply move the count of players into class.js, but in my actual app I could not do that.

Comment: could you add some code? I don't understand if you are using `global` or not.

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon im not using a global keyword if that's what you're asking... which may be what my problem is. Refresh in a few moments, I'll add some psuedocode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code would help but assuming I understand this correctly, you have something pseudocode like:

```
export class Class{
  constructor(){
    this.name = "foo";
  }
  usersOnline(){
   return main.connectedPlayers();
  }
}

-----

require('Class.js');

function connectedPlayers(){
  // stuff...
  return [Object]
}

...
var class1 = new Class();

console.log(class1.name); // correctly gives "foo"
console.log(class1.usersOnline()); // gives main not defined
```

This is because class.js has no links to the main class.  Just because the object is initialized in main.js doesn't mean the object knows what is happening outside it.  You need to tell the Object on creation, what it's part of.  A common method is to hand down the 'context' of the main class.  (mileage will vary)

```
constructor(context){
  this.name = "foo";
  this.main = context;
}

---

var class1 = new Class(this);
```

Now on creation the class knows which object is should reference when it's asked to run its usersOnline() function.

Note there are more elegant ways to do this then the method I have listed but the method I'm listing is hopefully indicative of the idea that is generally implemented in more elegant ways [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48695434/how-to-replace-bindthis-in-es6) for another method and some more links.

Comment: Interesting, this, and the post you linked make sense but seem like hacks to get the job done. Are you aware of if this is the general consensus on how to do this? The way I would likely go with would be the arrow function notation to get the correct context as laid out in the post you linked, but would you know if there is some sort of performance or memory sacrifice for doing that?

Comment: Arrow function notation is the current recommended practice and as far as performance or memory sacrifice is concerned, as far I know from the various frameworks I've seen this separation and reference back to the main class is one of the more effective ways of performing this operation (within the confines of Javascript).  Doing it this way avoid the function down into every instance.

Naturally their are other ways and depending on what you're doing push notifications to registered end-users might be better.  I found another page that may help: https://javascript.info/bind

Comment: Wait, on some more thought about it, wouldn't changing the context of the method make the method lose properties about the object its being called from? For example lets say usersOnline() returned this.id, and connectedPlayers, with this.id being the id property of the object usersOnline was being called from. Would changing the context make this.id undefined?

Comment: Not sure I understand but it would depend in my example on whether you listed in the usersOnline() for "this.id" or "main.id" for where it would look for the id variable. If inside connectedPlayers() you asked for "this.id" even though the connectedPlayers() function is being executed as a result of the usersOnline() function, the connectedPlayers() function is based in the main class and you'll get main.id as the output.

Comment: I updated my psuedo code to better describe what I meant, but I recognize in your example that passing the context as a variable would solve my problem. I don't yet have a firm grasp on context and how it really works besides the basics of the scope of different blocks so maybe I'm just having a hard time grasping it. Would the context I pass into my class to be stored be useful to me if my class is initialized inside of another function inside main? Would it not just pass the context of the function that new class(id) was called in?

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/javascript-context-this-keyword-9a78a19d5786 read it slowly, take it in and re-read sections slowly.  Understanding context is quite important especially for any decent javascript frameworks.  I recommend doing the examples a bit on your own setup.  

If you bind your function to an object in main and then later call that object, you would need to pass down the main context to the object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217725/discussion-between-varanus-and-ralph).

Comment: Came back two days later to realize what you meant by writing the context down lol I was being as dumb as possible. That is 100% the common answer (as I see it often in other modules) and the most efficient way to do it. Thank you! I must've been off my rocker.